# ClickOnce Unknown Publisher

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have created a ClickOnce for a simple .net console app in vs2012.
I have set the Publisher Name in the Publish --> Options --> Description --> Publisher Name.
However, when I run the setup.exe I still see Publisher: Unknown Publisher.

Why is it not picking up the Publisher Name that I have set?

Comment: Did you see this link when searching http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign your application with a code-signing certificate to ensure that only your company is submitting data to Microsoft, and this will add a layer of security that goes beyond the traditional user name and password.

Refer these links below:

[remove smartscreen filter](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/).

[msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh801887.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must always sign the ClickOnce deployment and application manifests with a publisher certificate. Next, the certificate used to sign a ClickOnce application must be configured in the Trusted Publishers certificate store on the user's machine. And finally, the certificate authority that issued the certificate must be configured in the Trusted Root Certificate Authority certificate store on the user's machine. I'll peel back the layers of each of these three pieces in turn.